# How do I disable auto connect for bluetooth device?

Tags: bluetooth

I want to leave bluetooth on so I get texts to my fitbit, but when I do that, my phone will connect to my headset which I'm using for something else. I use this headset with my phone too and don't want to unpair it.

How do I disable auto connect for this headset or disable auto connect for my phone entirely?

S9+.

Comment: Possible dupe: [Disable Bluetooth auto connect for specific devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/202109/44325)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Bluetooth auto connect for specific devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/202109/disable-bluetooth-auto-connect-for-specific-devices)

Answer (score 0):

use (Bluetooth Manager Controller) App, and disable auto connect, turn off all the notifications, hide the app :)

Comment: Please provide more information about the app and a statement if you are associated with it.